# LDAP query from Chrome App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ldap, google-chrome-app

I believe javascript is constrained to use only HTTP, but I was curious if there is anything out there that can enable a chrome application to make an LDAP query from the client side (without having to go through my webserver to connect to the LDAP and check credentials). My goal here is to have my users login to the internal web application using their network credentials, without having to wait on my server to establish an HTTPS connection.

Also, are there any security concerns with a setup such as this?

Comment: Don't think so. Even if you could use js to create TCP connections to any server on any port directly from browser (WebSockets, maybe? Not sure how they work), you would have to implement the whole ldap protocol in javascript, which is no easy task even in most server-side languages.

Comment: It looks like somebody wrote an LDAP client for node https://github.com/jeremycx/node-ldap. Not sure if that gets you any closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Chrome app is indeed capable of doing what you want. You'd use the chrome.socket API to establish a connection directly with the LDAP server.

However, your question sets off several alarms. If your client code is separately checking LDAP for credentials, and querying the web application for content, then what's stopping a malicious or buggy client from skipping the LDAP step and just grabbing the content, without authorization, directly from the web app? If your web app assumes only trusted clients, then why bother actually checking LDAP at all? In real life, this design would be like handing a note to a bank teller saying "I don't need to show you my ID because I promise I already showed it to the security guard stationed outside the bank. Please give me all the money in my account." It's much more commonplace -- and secure -- for the credential check, be it LDAP or otherwise, to be done by the web application, behind HTTP/HTTPS. (OAuth is another story in terms of its mechanics, but in principle it's the same.)

"without having to wait on my server to establish an HTTPS connection": it's not clear at all what you mean by this. HTTPS has nothing to do with authentication (except to the extent it confirms that the server is authentic). Do you really mean SSL handshake speed? An SSL handshake is usually from 200-500 milliseconds. Unless yours is an unusual use case, this amount of time won't matter. And again, HTTPS as normally deployed is transport security having nothing to do with client authentication. Even if you'd figured out a nonstandard but valid way to authenticate clients, you'd still want the conversation to happen over SSL unless there were truly nothing sensitive about the content (in which case you probably wouldn't need intranet client authentication in the first place).

More questions are outstanding, but you haven't sufficiently explained your use case yet.

TL;DR: yes, you can do this with a Chrome app. But yes, there are **many** security concerns with this design.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should've also mentioned that I want this app to be able to query LDAP for information about other people at the company, similar to using Outlook's address book (name, email, title, photo, phone, etc).

Comment: The login is less for security and more so that I know "who" I'm "talking" to. Information displayed in the application is specific to the user. Authenticating with the LDAP seemed like the best way to limit the end-users ability to view other user's information at the same time as providing me somewhat reliable information on exactly who I'm talking to. In reality, everyone has access to the same information, I'm just pulling the bits of information that pertain to a particular person.

My apologies if I'm not explaining this clearly enough. cudos sowbug on the Answer! It's what I needed!